# How to find users who are logged in but not logged out and is still logged in today in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

The status 1 means Login and Status 0 means Logout. How do I find users who are logged in till now?

**Here's the table**

```
 user_id            time                        status  

    57              2015-10-21 09:00:00         1       
    57              2015-10-21 10:00:00         0          
    60              2015-10-21 12:30:00         1          
    55              2015-10-11 08:00:00         1       
    54              2015-10-21 09:00:00         1       
    54              2015-10-21 09:15:00         0       
    50              2015-10-21 08:15:00         1       
    49              2015-10-21 11:00:00         1       
    49              2015-10-21 11:00:00         0
```

Expected Result :

```
 user_id            status                          

    55              1       
    60              1          
    55              1          
    50              1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want users whose more recent status is `0`.

Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from thetable t
where t.status = 1 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from thetable t2
                  where t2.user_id = t.user_id and
                        t2.status = 0 and
                        t2.time > t.time
                 );
```

This can take advantage of two indexes:  `thetable(status, user_id)` and `thetable(user_id, status, time)`.

Comment: thanks! that worked but I don't have any idea how you could come up with a solution that quickly! I mean I know SQL joins and all the things you used here but will take hours to find something like this on my own. Any tips or tutorials to learn this ?! :)

Answer (score 0):

While the query presented so far is the most straightforward on I would like to show an alternative variant:

The number of entries of a user who is not logged in at the moment is alway even (pairs of 1 and 0). If a user is logged in, the number is odd.

Consequently:

```
select user_id, count(*), sum(status) from tee
group by user_id having count(*)/sum(status) <> 2
```